# script to log temperature on armbian

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, temperature, armbian

I am aware that there are other questions asking very similar questions, but none seems to answer my problem. I am running an odroid hc2 sbc with armbian for a nextcloud instance. Two days ago, it crashed, for the first time, after running stable for over a year. To rule out overheating as a reason, I'd like to write a script to monitor temperature, i.e. running the built in function "armbianmonitor", which creates this continous output:

```
Stop monitoring using [ctrl]-[c]
Time       big.LITTLE   load %cpu %sys %usr %nice %io %irq   CPU  C.St.

09:52:33:  600/ 600MHz  0.23  12%   1%  10%   0%   0%   0% 53.0°C  0/13
09:52:38: 1400/ 600MHz  0.21   2%   0%   1%   0%   0%   0% 53.0°C  0/13
09:52:43: 1400/ 600MHz  0.20   2%   0%   1%   0%   0%   0% 53.0°C  0/13^C
```

with:

```
sudo armbianmonitor -m | awk '$11 ~ "°C" {print $1; print $1;exit1}' ORS=' '
```

I get this results:

```
09:57:48: 53.0°C 09:57:53: 51.0°C 09:57:58: 51.0°C 09:58:03: 51.0°C
```

but... I'd like to have only one pair (time and temperature) per run of the script. In other word, awk and /or (?) armbianmonitor are supposed to stop after they return the first pair. I've also tried to pipe the output of a script invoking this command to a file, but the file remains blank, maybe because armbianmonitor creates a continuous output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a slightly different path and now do the following:

executed every minute:

```
#!/bin/bash

dttm=$(date +"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M;")
temp=$(echo $(cat /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp) /1000 | bc)

echo $dttm $temp
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [page](https://ameridroid.com/blogs/ameriblogs/how-to-monitor-soc-temperature-in-armbian-at-the-command-prompt), access this file:

`/etc/armbianmonitor/datasources/soctemp`

Example one second watch:

```
watch -n 1 cat /etc/armbianmonitor/datasources/soctemp
```